# What are the advantages of django-channels over python websockets?

Tags: python, django

Before people were using python websockets with django for websocket handling. Now the django-channels came as an official django project which supports django to handle websockets. can anyone list the advantage of django channels over python websockets in terms of django web development?

One point would be,

- Since channels built for django web development, it would be well integrated with django framework.

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: django channels and websockets are 2 different things which you can't compare.

Comment: Both handles websocket right? Could you please explain your comment?

Comment: Ok, I might be wrong here, as it seems to include more than I expected.

Answer (score 5):

Django channels is not just a library for WebSockets:

> Channels is a project to make Django able to handle more than just plain HTTP requests, including WebSockets and HTTP2, as well as the ability to run code after a response has been sent for things like thumbnailing or background calculation. ([docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).

In your particular case (WebSockets), Channels makes it easier to work with them, as it extends Django providing all the required components (the [Daphne server](https://github.com/django/daphne), [asgi_redis](https://github.com/django/asgi_redis/), etc). It also provides an interface to them that resembles that of views, making it easier for Django developers.

It also adds some other useful functionality, such as [data binding](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/binding.html), [routing](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/routing.html) or [groups](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html#groups), which are things you are likely to use, saving you the burden of implementing them yourself.

In short: it makes WebSocket handling much easier :)